# WCF Service with Net.TCP Binding unable to write to event log

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-7, event-log, net.tcp

I have a service hosted in IIS 7 over net.tcp which throws an error when writing to the Application event log because of invalid permissions:

Message: Requested registry access is not allowed.

Which account do I need to give permission to and where do I need to do it?

Comment: What is the API you are using to write to even log? Did you consider writing just to log files using NLog?

Comment: @field_b Are you trying to create a custom event log or write to an existing log?

Comment: @grizzly: I am writing to Windows Application event log.

Comment: @Dhawalk: I have not used NLog before. I will look into it.